# How to CodeSign for upload to iTunesConnect

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, code-signing, app-store-connect

It has been a few months since I have code signed an app and I can't remember exactly what do I need to do?
Everything is 100% ready except this

Comment: Same thing you did last time: read Apple's docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read all the docs that other users suggested you to (re)read.
2. Update/create provision profile for distribution, set status of app in `iTunesConnect` **Waiting for upload**.
3. Sign your application in Xcode with this profile
4. Select `iOS Device`
5. `Product->Archive`
6. If build was successfully ended then `Organizer` will open. Submit your application.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two apple docs that you should (re)read from Apple's iOS Development Guide:

[Building and Running Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html)

[Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW1)

These walk you through the code signing identities. Read them. Bookmark them.